# Bash unzip file and add timestamp in name

Tags: bash, unzip

I have zip with structure

```
temp.zip

- file.csv
- readme.txt
- license.txt
```

How unzip temp.zip, with add timestamp in name,
result:

```
file.142345687.csv
readme.142345687.txt
license.142345687.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List files using the `-l` option, then extract them one-by-one using the `-p` option:

```
unzip -l -q -q temp.zip | awk '{print $NF}' | while read file
do
  unzip -p temp.zip "${file}" > "${file%.*}.$(date +%s).${file##*.}"
done
```

where

- `-q -q` options ask for a silent output (in easy-to-parse columns);
- `awk`'s `$NF` points to the last column;
- `${file%.*}` deletes the shortest match of `.*` from back of the filename;
- `${file##*.}` deletes the longest match of `*.` from the front of the filename;
- `$(date +%s)` outputs seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this;

```
#!/bin/bash
unzip temp.zip
for n in $(unzip -Z -1 "temp.zip"); do 
  e=${n#*.}
  fn="${n%.*}"
  DATE=`date +%s`
  newFileName="$filename.$DATE.$e"
  mv "$n" "$newFileName"
done
```